# iOS container for an iPhone app written in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Coming from Android, I got used to Dagger as my main DI framework.
Recently, I joined a new iPhone project written in Objective-C which have no DI framework.

I would like to add one to our project, and I wonder which one is the best one to use, when it comes to simplicity and performance.

I would like to hear your opinion and experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection is a popular design pattern in many languages, such as Java and C#, but it hasn’t seen widespread adoption in Objective-C (yet!).
[This](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/dependency-injection-give-your-ios-code-a-shot-in-the-arm-ba98594f5002#.fx4pxnnpb) is an excellent read to get you started on DI is Objective-C.
 Additionally, you'll find [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/), [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/dependency-injection-ios/) & the Grand Daddy [this](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) indispensable for DI in iOS.
 
[This](http://typhoonframework.org/) framework seems to be making a lot of noise these days.

*In my personal experience*, more than anything else DI helps you a *lot* in testing. 
It's *not* `all or nothing` approach (which is common for many design patterns) allows for easy, no-cost adoption & definitely valuable returns.

Comment: Thanks. Is it the same story with Swift?

Comment: Yes, not much of a difference. It's an eco-system thing. But there sure are marvelous apps out there adhering to DI strictly.